# @keyframes animation text fade and shine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to coding this text animation effect ([please see video](http://www.fourhandscircus.com/Main_Home_GFG.mp4)) but i'm quite far from solution!!

Can you please help me? maybe is better using js?

```css
h1.fadeinone { animation: fadeinone 10s;}
h1.fadeintwo { animation: fadeintwo 10s;}
h1.fadeinthree { animation: fadeinthree 10s;}

@keyframes fadeinone {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33% { /* 3s for fade in */
    opacity: 1;
  }

}

@keyframes fadeintwo {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  66% { /* 3s for fade in */
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeinthree{
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% { /* 3s for fade in */
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#claim h1 {

font-size: 40px;
line-height:40px; 
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
color:#FFF;
}

#claim {background-color:red;}
```

```html
<div id="claim">
<h1 class="fadeinone">DESIGN</h1>
<h1 class="fadeintwo">loren ipsum</h1>
<h1 class="fadeinthree">DOLOR SIT</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please state the exact error or problem you're experiencing so that focussed answers can be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `animation-delay` property. It's a bit tedious, because you'll have to separate out each letter of each line into its own element (I used `span` in this case), and then you'll have to manually assign each `span` its own delay, but the effect matches what you provided.

Also, by using this method, you only need one set of keyframes, because you'll be using the delay to determine when the animation starts, rather than using a percentage over multiple animations.

```css
div span
{
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

div span:nth-child(1){animation-delay:0s}
div span:nth-child(2){animation-delay:0.2s}
div span:nth-child(3){animation-delay:0.4s}
div span:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0.6s}
div span:nth-child(5){animation-delay:0.8s}
div span:nth-child(6){animation-delay:1s}

@keyframes fadein
{
  0%{opacity: 0}
  100%{opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>D</span><span>E</span><span>S</span><span>I</span><span>G</span><span>N</span>
</div>
```

Of course, you could do this with Javascript and the solution would likely be more elegant and easier to modify; however, then you have to deal with compatibility issues. You're going to be better off just sticking with strict CSS whenever possible.

Comment: Thank your solution was perfect!!

www.gfgstyle.it